# Como iniciar una nueva gestion en sql server

Tags: sql-server

Hola chavales mi pregunta es como puedo iniciar una base de datos con información 0 , bueno me explico tengo una base de datos q dice CCN2019 esta contiene todos los registros de del año en curso, pero ahora necesito crear una nueva base de datos con el nombre de CCN2020 pero con tablas limpias sin informacion del año 2019 y asi continuar una nueva gestion de informacion en CCN2020

Comment: Vas a crear una base de datos cada año? yo que tú, seguía usando la misma base de datos, cambiar a una nueva no te trae ninguna ventaja.

Comment: Apoyo la sugerencia de Javier. Hacer una base de datos cada año terminará siendo un dolor de cabeza para obtener datos históricos y comparativas.